# Turn off colors using listings package in Beamer

Tags: beamer, listings

I am using different languages in my Beamer presentation: C++, Assembler. For terminal output I have defined:

```
\lstdefinestyle{bash-output-style}{
    basicstyle=\small\ttfamily\color{solarized@base00},
    keywordstyle=\color{solarized@base00},
    numberstyle=\tiny\color{solarized@base00},
    stringstyle=\color{solarized@base00},
    backgroundcolor=\color{solarized@base3},
}
```

I am using it in the following way:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[style=bash-output-style]
    tiny2:     file format elf32-i386
    Disassembly of section .text:
    08048080 <_start>:
\end{lstlisting}
```

The problem is that keywords, strings, numbers are colored differently. Is there a way to set all the output text to a single color? I have set keywordstyle, numberstyle etc. to the same value, but it seems that it has no effect.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436). It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: Putting together a complete example for me produces text of the same color. So there is something else that you are doing that you are not telling us.  Without a compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) we'd just have to guess at the cause of the problem.

Comment: I checked my code and found, that I had at the beginning a global `\lstset{style=solarized-light}` statement which caused the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an error made by the OP.